# predict() function from rma object producing results that are too large

Tags: r, linear-regression, random-effects, metafor

I'm trying to produce partial regressions based on an rma object:

```
tmc<-rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ temp_annual_range+max_temp+min_temp+Wildfire, method="ML", data=formsc)
```

Based on  this, I want to predict the model outcome based on each predictor, whilst keeping the others constant at their means. Variables are continuous apart from Wildfire (binary), first I obtained the means:

```
meantemprange<-mean(formsc$temp_annual_range)
```

```
meanmaxtemp<-mean(formsc$max_temp)
```

```
meanmintemp<-mean(formsc$min_temp)
```

Then I use the predict() function to predict the model based on the values for temp _ annual _ range and but keeping the other variables constant at their means..

```
outputc <- as.data.frame (predict(tmc,newmods=cbind(temp_annual_range,meanmaxtemp,meanmintemp,1)))
```

The predicted values generated are crazy large, two orders of magnitude larger than the measured values of 'yi' in the original dataset (formsc). Is there any glaringly obvious issue with my code?

I want to use the predicted values from the model and the temp annual range values to produce a partial plot. Is there another way of doing this without using predict() in the way that I am?

Please find full code and subset of data here: github.com/jmk85/datformsc.git

Comment: We don't have your data, so we can't run your code.  Please include data using `dput` to make your code reproducible.

Comment: Maybe the new data isn't inputted properly with the `cbind()`? From the looks of this, it won't be a data.frame with the names "temp_annual_range", "max_temp" etc. Also the variable is called `meantemprange`, but not used like this in the cbind. Possibly the order doesn't match with the input. Can confirm by instead making a data.frame of the same structure as `formsc` e.g. `data.frame(temp_annual_range=meantemprange, max_temp=meanmaxtemp, ... )` instead

Comment: Actually, the syntax looks right (`newmods` should be a matrix, not a data frame), but I can't see what the `temp_annual_range` variable that is used in `cbind()` actually contains and how that matches up with the `temp_annual_range` variable that was used in the fitted model. As shown, the line should generate an error, since `temp_annual_range` is a variable in `formsc`, and so it won't be found unless there is another `temp_annual_range` variable in the global workspace. In any case, without a reproducible example, this is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for your insights all

Please find full code and subset of data here:

https://github.com/jmk85/datformsc.git